# Skins for apache trinidad

Tags: java, apache, jsf, trinidad

Hi I would like to know how to use a skin with trinidad. i have created a eclipse project with JSF 1.2 ( apache myfaces ), JSTL, Apache Trinidad 1.2.14. in my project i also created a trinidad-config.xml with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <trinidad-config xmlns="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/config">
    <skin-family>casablanca</skin-family>
</trinidad-config>
```

i think casablanca is default skin for trinidad 1.2 but i still put it to make sure.
( The only reason i used trinidad 1.2 is because i am not aware if there is any inbuild modern skin for trinidad 2.0 ).

Anyways, now i create my index.jsp with following inside the body tag

```
<f:view>
<tr:form>
    <tr:panelTabbed>
      <tr:showDetailItem text="Apache Trinidad Components" >
      </tr:showDetailItem>
      <tr:showDetailItem text="Architecture">
      </tr:showDetailItem>
      <tr:showDetailItem text="Release">
      </tr:showDetailItem>
    </tr:panelTabbed>
</tr:form>
</f:view>
```

And the result i am expecting is something like http://example.irian.at/trinidad-components-showcase/component-demo/panelTabbed-Default

but all i get is a ugly page ( http://imagebin.org/163630 ) with links instead of 3 tabs. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Remember, your page must have the tr:document tag on the page to kick off the skin framework" from
http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/devguide/skinning.html